# Python type hinting: how to handle long, optional return values going into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a function:

```
def foo() -> Union[
    Optional[bool], Optional[int], Optional[str]
]:
    pass
```

How should I hint the variable that calls this function? It's so long, this seems wrong?

```
def bar() -> None:
    """
    Do something
    """
    baz: Union[
    Optional[bool], Optional[int], Optional[str] = foo()
```

Comment: Surely it would be easier to just say `Union[None, bool, int, str]` since that does the same thing right?

Comment: A return value of `Union[bool, int, str]` is already a bit suspect. Why does your function need to return so many different types of values?

Comment: I think that author just want to demonstrate more complex return type. Of course in this case he could use `Any` .

Comment: @PeterTrcka Yeah, just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the specific type

```py
FooType = Optional[Union[bool, str, int]]
```

And then use it:

```py
def foo() -> FooType:
    pass

def bar() -> None:
    baz: FooType = foo()
```